# Использование ресурсов социальных сетей и медиа сайтов

Tags: вконтакте, youtube, facebook

Как использовать материалы социальных сетей (facebook, vkontakte, google+) и, например, таких сайтов как youtube в своём сайте?

Каждый материал имеет свою ссылку, например, фото вконтакте. Я могу сохранить ссылку и в своём сайте кидать тег img с src равным этой ссылке. Но как создать удобный интерфейс для пользователя? Нет, конечно, можно заставить пользователя вызвать контекстное меню для фотографии или видео, скопировать url и вставить в каком-нибудь диалоге на своём сайте...

Хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь, кликнувши на фото вконтакте и после того как появилась фотография на странице контакта, он просто скопировал адресную строку (без контекстного меню и т.д.) в диалог на моём сайте. Но этот адрес какая-та абакадабра...

Вот суть проблемы. Буду признателен за любые предложения и советы.

Comment: А если парсить по ссылке теги `<a>` вот например для ВК вам нужно оттуда достать значение `z_src`:

    <a id="profile_photo_link" href="/photoNN_MM" onclick="return showPhoto('NN_MM', 'albumNN_M/rev', {temp: {x_src: &quot;http://cs4472.vkontakte.ru/uNN/MM/x_XX.jpg&quot;, y_src: &quot;http://cs4472.vkontakte.ru/uNN/MM/y_YY.jpg&quot;, z_src: &quot;http://cs4472.vkontakte.ru/uNN/MM/z_ZZ.jpg&quot;}, big: 1, dark: 1}, event)">

Comment: это "profile_photo" а как на счёт других фотографий? и в других соцсетях?

Comment: вооооооооообще то насколько я знаю...у всех более менее адвокатных сетей есть внизу кнопочка "Для разработчиков" логично предположить что там должна лежать какая то инфа по вашей теме...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует масса способов решения вашей задачи. Прежде всего для самых крупных соц. сетей есть свои API: [vkontakte.API](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php), [facebook.API](http://developers.facebook.com/), etc.
Сделать универсальное решение - невозможно. Для каждой соц.сети вам необходимо разработать отдельный модуль. Но некоторые постоянные ссылки справедливы для всех популярных соц.сетей. По этому пример, приведенный выше с вконтакте, справедлив для остальных. А тот же google+, flickr и picasa тоже имеют свои прекрасные API с обёртками на PHP, Python (подозреваю, что и для других языков тоже).

Comment: Вот...я про это и говорил :DDD украл идею с комента %)